# How can I apply a dynamic mask in an dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a problem with my dynamic form. This input is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="EX: (XX)-XXXX-XXXX" name="phone[]" id="phone">
```

This input have a mask

```
$('#phone').mask('(00)-0000-00000');
```

Everything works fine, but when I add a button who append a new input after the first the .mask filter doesn't work to the new .
How can I apply a dynamic mask in an dynamic form?

The .append function is:

```
$('#plusPhone').click(function(){
   $('#appendPhone').append("<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-md-6\"><div class=\"form-group\"><label class=\"control-label col-md-3\">Phone</label><div class=\"col-md-9\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"EX: (XX)-XXXX-XXXX\" name=\"phone[]\" id=\"phone\"></div></div></div></div>");   });
```

Comment: Where do you add the mask to the new input?

Comment: @Markai At the end of page: <script>jQuery(document).ready(function() {  $('#phone').mask('(00)-0000-00000'); });</script>
.mask function is this plugin> [link]http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/

Comment: But when you add a new input, you need to also add a mask to that new object, too: `$('#phone').mask('(00)-0000-00000');` after `$('#appendPhone').append[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add it dynamically just like this. 
This is an untested code but the idea remains the same.

```
$('#plusPhone').click(function(){
  $('#appendPhone').append("<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-md-6\"><div class=\"form-group\"><label class=\"control-label col-md-3\">Phone</label><div class=\"col-md-9\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"EX: (XX)-XXXX-XXXX\" name=\"phone[]\" id=\"phone\"></div></div></div></div>"); 

  var code = "<script>$('#telefone').mask('(00)-0000-00000');</scr"+"ipt>";
  $('#appendPhone').append($(code)[0]);
)};
```

Here is an example of how to execute js by appending it dynamically in htmls - [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/dLsxL5Lb/)
This way you can append the code snippet to dynamically created htmls. Hope it helps

Comment: I tryed this but don't work. I added this to my append and the same... not work =/
`$('#appendPhone').append("<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-md-6\"><div class=\"form-group\"><label class=\"control-label col-md-3\">Phone</label><div class=\"col-md-9\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"EX: (XX)-XXXX-XXXX\" name=\"phone[]\" id=\"phone\"></div></div></div></div><script>$('#phone').mask('(00)-0000-00000');</scr"+"ipt>");`

Comment: I corrected a typo, BTW, what do you really want to mask. Your code doesnt have anything with the id `telephone`. Could show your code exactly ?

Comment: So do you mean, this mask should appear the moment your dynamic html is added or when some button is clicked. Not quite clear :)

Comment: I tryed use the .clone().insertAfter() but the same occurs... =/

Answer (score 0):

Pamio is on the right track. But appending the script to the page doesn't seem to work(?).
The following works for me:

```
$('#plusPhone').click(function(){
   var HTML = 'this contains an input field with the class you want to mask';
   jQuery('#element-you-want-to-append-to').append(HTML);
   jQuery('.class-you-want-masked').mask('99-99-9999');
   //Just call the mask AFTER appending the input, and it should be applied.
)};
```