# Run script in append() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem regarding run script in append() function, for more detail see my code below :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Item Pekerjaan" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="volume[]" placeholder="vol.." style="width:80px;" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="satuan[]" placeholder="etc.." style="width:80px;" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="material[]" placeholder="Harga Volume" class="form-control name_list" id="currency"/></td><td><input type="text" name="jasa[]" placeholder="Harga Jasa" class="form-control name_list" id="currency1"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });    
 });  
 </script>
```

in code above i can't run jQuery MaskMoney for `id="currency"`in jasa or material form.

Is there anyone can give me suggestion for this case?

Thanks for your help.

================================

Javascrypt Maskmoney :

```
       $(function() {
            $("#currency").maskMoney({
                formatOnBlur: true,
                reverse: true,
                prefix: 'Rp ',
                selectAllOnFocus: true,
                precision: 0
            });
            $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
                var v = $("#currency").maskMoney('destroy').val()
                        .replace(/Rp\s|[.,]/g, '');
                $("#currency").val(v);
            });
});
```

Comment: — Could you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: provide HTML as well

Comment: It's work fine in my end can you show html and tell me what error you getting?

Comment: can you tell me in which textbox you want MaskMoney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a piece of advice, you're generating multiple elements in your DOM with the same `id`. You better don't do that, because `id` is designed to be unique (use classes instead).

About your question, you should invoke MaskMoney after you add the row, so it can apply it to the new created element...

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Item Pekerjaan" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="volume[]" placeholder="vol.." style="width:80px;" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="satuan[]" placeholder="etc.." style="width:80px;" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="material[]" placeholder="Harga Volume" class="form-control name_list" id="currency"/></td><td><input type="text" name="jasa[]" placeholder="Harga Jasa" class="form-control name_list" id="currency1"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
           $('tr#row'+i).find('input#currency, input#currency1')
                        .maskMoney({                                                                       
                            formatOnBlur: true,
                            reverse: true,
                            prefix: 'Rp ',
                            selectAllOnFocus: true,
                            precision: 0
                        }); 
      });    
 });
```

But you better do it with classes...

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">' +
                                        '<td><input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Item Pekerjaan" class="form-control name_list"/></td>' +
                                        '<td><input type="text" name="volume[]" placeholder="vol.." style="width:80px;" class="form-control name_list"/></td>' +
                                        '<td><input type="text" name="satuan[]" placeholder="etc.." style="width:80px;" class="form-control name_list"/></td>' +
                                        '<td><input type="text" name="material[]" placeholder="Harga Volume" class="form-control name_list" class="currency"/></td>' +
                                        '<td><input type="text" name="jasa[]" placeholder="Harga Jasa" class="form-control name_list" class="currency"/></td>' +
                                        '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td>' +
                                      '</tr>');
           $('tr#row'+i+' input.currency').maskMoney({                                                                       
                                              formatOnBlur: true,
                                              reverse: true,
                                              prefix: 'Rp ',
                                              selectAllOnFocus: true,
                                              precision: 0
                                          });  
      });    
 });
```

Comment: it's work, but mask money format was different with my form before, because i have own maskmoney format, see in my question, i already added it in my question...
to see the different that i mean, you can see in my capture below  [link]http://prntscr.com/h1ojbp

Comment: You have to apply the `.maskMoney()` with your options (you don't show that call in your question, so I can't know what options are). Use the same call that you used in the initilization.

Comment: Oh! I see you edit the question and now it shows the maskMonkey options. I've edited the answer. Good to hear that it's working! Have a nice day and happy coding!

Comment: sorry @A. Iglesias , i found new problem after implemented new maskmoney format, see my code    `$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var v = $('#currency, #currency1').maskMoney('destroy').val()
      .replace(/Rp\s|[.,]/g, '');
    $('#currency, #currency1').val(v);
   });`

after i click submit button, all form data with id="currency" was changed into value as same as with first form value, i used that javascrypt code for delete money format, so just save number data without maskmoney format, for more detail see my capture below : [link]http://prntscr.com/h3tpjs

Comment: if you're online, may you give me suggestion again? i confused with javascript because i'm new.. thx..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Item Pekerjaan" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="volume[]" placeholder="vol.." style="width:80px;" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="satuan[]" placeholder="etc.." style="width:80px;" class="form-control name_list"/></td><td><input type="text" name="material[]" placeholder="Harga Volume" class="form-control name_list" id="currency'+$i+'"/></td><td><input type="text" name="jasa[]" placeholder="Harga Jasa" class="form-control name_list" id="currency1"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
           $('#currency'+i).maskMoney(); 
      });  

 });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check this solution

[How can I apply a dynamic mask in an dynamic form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909869/how-can-i-apply-a-dynamic-mask-in-an-dynamic-form)

You are facing the similar problem i guess.

Comment: this should be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: @cwang: sorry for that. new to stackoverflow.I will remember that next time. Thanks for suggesting the proper way of using it :)